# I get a lot of FallingSand where I need FallingBlock. Is there a way to get that to work easily?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Say I want to summon a big build. I look for commands, and I find FallingSand, but I am playing Minecraft Java Edition 1.15. How do I easily change that?

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way. There are some 1.12→1.13 command converters online that can do this for you, otherwise you need to re-create the commands. For that, you need to understand them, I recommend the [Minecraft wiki](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com).

Here is an example for summoning a falling stone block:

```
/summon falling_block ~ ~ ~ {Time:1,BlockState:{Name:"stone"}}
```